# AngularJS : Dependency injection ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please if anyone could help me,

I'm having a problem with ngResource, I've been searching for a solution for 2 hours but haven't found anything so I decided to put a question even though there are similar questions about this subject!

I'm using AngularJS version 1.4.7

I've been working with services just fine and then decided to use $resource,

the web service return a list of commercials.

here is app.js :

```
var myApp = angular.module('btAngApp' , ['ngMessages','ngResource'])
.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.endPoint = "http://localhost:8082/serverprject/rest/";
});
```

the factory :

```
myApp.factory('commercialFactory', function($rootScope, $resource){
    return $resource($rootScope + 'commercial/findall');
});
```

the controller :

```
myApp.controller('editComCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $http, commercialFactory) {
$scope.init = function(){
    $scope.getAll();
};

$scope.getAll = function(){
    $scope.commercials = commercialFactory.query();
}

$scope.init();
```

I'm using $http and $filter in another code following the controller code above, I didn't copy it here.

I have included all the files above in index.html and 
downloaded angular-resource.min.js.

I've tried many scenarios but same error (make the controller and factory in the same file, have the code of the factory inside of the controller, ....)
if I don't inject ngResource in angular.module I get this error :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20editComCtrl

If I do I get this :

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=btAngApp&p1=%5B%24inj....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the factory :

```
return $resource($rootScope + 'commercial/findall');
```

maybe this should be: `$rootScope.endPoint + 'commercial/findall'`

---

For the provider error, instead, you should ensure that ngResource will be loaded before your app, and, of course, after angularjs

Comment: oh yes my mistake, for the provider I did as you told me, now it's working just having little issues with my url.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In the factory you are returning the resource object directly.

In the factory you should have some methods or variable which you can access it using the factory

I guess you should assign it to some variable and then return so that you can access it using the factory.

something like this..

```
 return {
            resourceHandle: $resource($rootScope + 'commercial/findall')
    }
```

and then use it in the controller as

```
$scope.getAll = function(){

    $scope.commercials = commercialFactory.resourceHandle.query();
}

$scope.init();
```

Comment: it didn't work , I got a syntax error
The error I'm getting now is : Error: $resource:badcfgResponse does not match configured parameter.

Comment: missed the one point as mentioned above by Hitmands... $rootScope.endPoint + 'commercial/findall'.

Comment: The issue that you are mentioning is regarding the method that you are invoking on the resouce object ......I guess the issue is the the method you are calling... instead of query tryi calling get method

Comment: Yes, the problem was from the method; I 'm stuggling a little bit because i'm still learning. Thank you so much for your help